# Perl- Iterating through an array of hashes with square brackets

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have a hash whose keys is a string and key is array(the complication is that the array is defined in the square bracket), So my hash is like this..

```
model = {
       'add'     =>  [
                      {'name' => 'abc1', 'value' => 'def' },
                      {'name' => 'abc2', value => 'ghi'} 
                     ],
       'remove'  =>  [
                       {'name' => 'abc1', 'value' => 'def' },
                       {'name' => 'abc2', value => 'ghi'}
                     ]
     };
```

So what I am trying to achive is that when I try to iterate through the hashes of array 
model->{add} as

```
print $_->{name} foreach(model->{add})
```

it doesnt work.
I guess this is because the array is in [] instead of ().
Considering the input cannot be changed. please let me know how to get through this...

Comment: a great place to start is [perldoc perlreftut](http://p3rl.org/reftut) which should explain in just a few simple rules how to do anything you need with data structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$model = { 'add' => [ {'name' => 'abc1', 'value' => 'def' },
                  {'name' => 'abc2', 'value' => 'ghi'} ],
       'remove' => [ {'name' => 'abc1', 'value' => 'def' },
                     {'name' => 'abc2', 'value' => 'ghi'} ] };

print $_->{name} foreach( @{ $model->{add} } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a 3-level nested structure: A HashRef containing ArrayRefs containing HashRefs.

```
my $model = { 
    'add' => [ 
        {
            'name' => 'abc1', 
            'value' => 'def' 
        }, {
            'name' => 'abc2', 
            value => 'ghi'
        } 
    ], 
    'remove' => [ 
        {
            'name' => 'abc1', 
            'value' => 'def' 
        }, {
            'name' => 'abc2', 
            value => 'ghi'
        } 
    ] 
};
```

To access those nested arrays and hashes, you need to dereference them, by adding `%` or `@` in front of it, depending on whether it is a hash or array.

```
my $arrayref = $model->{add};

foreach my $hashref (@$arrayref) {
    print $hashref->{name}, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Is there any method to get the values of key 'name' in an array with out iterating through it?

Comment: @user1737619 No. Each element in the array needs to be accessed individually, so iteration is required.

Comment: You could access the element directly, e.g. `$model->{add}[0]{name}`. But that will only get you the value for the first item in the array. If there can only be 2 elements in the array, you could do the same thing for the second, `$model->{add}[1]{name}`. But if there are more than that, you'll probably have to iterate. Generally I would recommend iterating anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The statement:

```
print $_->{name} foreach(model->{add})
```

Does not work because `model` is a bareword, not a variable. If you have these two pragmas in your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You will not be able to make mistakes like this. `warnings` will tell you:

```
Unquoted string "model" may clash with future reserved word at ...
Name "main::model" used only once: possible typo at ...
Use of uninitialized value in print at ...
```

And `strict` will tell you:

```
Can't use bareword ("model") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ...
```

However, if you do not have those two pragmas enabled, Perl will happily print the empty string and be silent about the whole thing. Which makes the mistake rather hard to detect.

The correct way to handle this is to grab the correct scalar value from the hash, and dereference it using the correct sigil. If you look at the key `'add'`:

```
'add'     =>  [
```

You'll see that it has an array reference stored in it, which means the sigil to use is `@`. You'll need support curly braces to disambiguate the references. Also, you have to refer to your variable as `$model`.

```
print $_->{name} for @{ $model->{add} };
```

Which is the same as

```
my $adds = $model->{add};
print $_->{name} for @$adds;
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost use `use strict; use warnings;`

The scalar `model` should be written as

```
my $model = { 'add' => [ {'name' => 'abc1', 'value' => 'def' }, {'name' => 'abc2', value => 'ghi'} ], 'remove' => [ {'name' => 'abc1', 'value' => 'def' }, {'name' => 'abc2', value => 'ghi'} ] };
```

and

```
print $_->{name} foreach( ( @{ $model->{ add } } ) );
```

Comment: Doesnt work Error:                                                         Pseudo-hashes are deprecated at ab.pl line 9.
Can't use string ("value") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use at ab.pl line 9.

Comment: @user1737619 Edited, Check now